# Topology and a Set

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a set. We say that a topology on $X$ has the set as an element. Can we say that the topology ‘contains’ the set? Which is correct? $X\subset \mathcal T$ or $X \in \mathcal T$? If $X$ is an element of $\mathcal T$ can we say $\mathcal T$ contains $X$? Or we keep the word ‘contain’ on in the case of subsets?

Comment: $X\in\mathcal T$ is correct. It certainly does not imply $X\subset\mathcal T$.

Comment: For example, if $X=\{x\}$ then $\mathcal T=\{\{x\}\}$ is a topology on $X$. Here, $X\in\mathcal T$ but $X\not\subset\mathcal T$ (i.e., $x\notin\{\{x\}\}$).

Comment: Yes notation-wise but are allowed use the word ‘contain’ or should we use only ‘element of’. English is a bit ambiguous here. I have a box of chocolates (chocolates are elements of the box) but here we can also say the box contains the chocolates.

Comment: Are you asking a linguistic question? Then most definitely Math SE is not a place for that.

Comment: In math (especially sets) you must be cautious in using the term "contains". If you use it then it must be crystal clear for the reader how it should be interpreted (subset or element).